# How do I add the permissions required to the OAuth Request to download a file?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have the quickstart working where it lists the files, and I have the code to download the file, but I do not know where/how to add the permissions to the OAuth2.0 request to allow the code to download files. I've been all over the console and cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not use a Web UI to manage these ahead of time. 
The scopes are a space-seperated string passed to client.flow_from_clientsecrets(). Adding new scopes will cause the user to have to confirm access.